# Configure pop-up in Experience Builder

Tags: arcgis-online, filter, popup, widget, arcgis-experience-builder

In Experience Builder, seems that a Filter widget, when launched will always dock at the bottom of the map window; my pop-ups for my web map also dock at the bottom.  Problem is, on a phone or other small device, they obscure each other, making it potentially hard for users to find info.

Only way I've seen to change pop-up position in the app. is if data is hosted in Enterprise....

Does anyone know of a potential way to change pop-up position (or filter) so that they don't always dock at the bottom of the app?

To be clear, this is an issue on a phone, not full window, which seems much more easily configurable...